# How to change variable based on checkbox being checked or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a checkbox like this...

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="something" name="something" value="25" data-val="25" checked="checked" class="option">
    <label for="something">Something</label>
```

I want to have javascript/jquery code where every time that checkbox is checked or unchecked, it looks to see if its checked and assigns a value of 25 if it's checked, or 0 if its not checked. However, when I test by checking/unchecking, it just keeps spitting out 25.  Why isn't it changing to 0 when I uncheck?  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.option').on('change', function() {
       if ($('#something').attr('checked')) {
          var something = 25;
      } else {
          var something = 0;
      }
      console.log(something);
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check checkbox checked property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** method returns  `string` **"checked"** -*Initial state of the checkbox, which doesn't change*.
 It will always be evaluated as `true`, and `if condition` will always run.

> To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected,
>   or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method.

So using **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** you can get `true/false` **values**:

```
$('.option').on('change', function() {
   var something;
   if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        something=25;
      } 
    else {
        something = 0;
      }
        console.log(something);
 });
```

Or you can **check** if the `checkbox` is checked with **[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)** method which returns `boolean`.

```
$('.option').on('change', function() {
      var something;
       if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          something=25;
      } else {
           something = 0;
      }
      console.log(something);
 });
```

Comment: Awesome, that did it. Learn something new everyday.  Thanks so much!